# Encode/decoded a randomized, fixed-length string to and from a 64 bit integer

Tags: algorithm, encoding, hash, decoding

I want to convert a fixed-length, say 50 character long randomized string into a 64 bit integer and be able to convert it back to original text given the 64 bit integer.

Does an algorithm exist for this? I want to go with encoding/decoding rather than hashing/reverse lookup.

Comment: Have you heard of the pigeonhole principle?  A 64 bit integer can hold 64 bits of data, which is 1.84e+19 different values. Which means at most, that many strings can be converted back and forth. If you assume the strings can ONLY be lowercase a-z, then you can only squeeze 13 characters into that.

Comment: This seems impossible in the general case - how are you going to be able to map all the possibilities of a 50-character string to a unique 64-bit value? The only scenario where it would be valid is if there are only two possible characters, in which case you could encode one as 0 and the other as 1. Or you would have to shorten the string, require that all valid strings follow a more easily compressible pattern, etc.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes I understand. Collisions are fine in my case I don't need uniqueness. But for fun let's go with your response of 13 characters a-z. How can I map between 64 bit integer and a 13 character long string randomized a-z string?

Comment: " into a 64 bit integer and be able to convert it back to original text given the 64 bit integer." That is fundamentally impossible if there are collisions. It requires uniqueness. [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: Have you done an exercise converting a base 10 number into a base 2 or base 16 number? (it's a common homework problem). In this case, you're simply converting a base 2 number into a base 32 number.

Comment: If your alphabet is 26 characters you need 5 bits per character. You can fit **12** characters into 64 bits with 4 unused bits left over.

Comment: You need uniqueness. Otherwise, you will not get back the same value when reversing the operation.

Answer (score 0):

just sumarization of the comments...

`1:1` mapping between string and number requires enough characters and bits to store your data. Assuming 26 char alphabet only:

```
64bit ->  2^64  // possible numbers in 64 bits
1char ->  26    // possible characters per 1 char
```

so in order to get the number of chars fitting into 64 bit integer

```
chars = floor( 64 / (log(26)/log(2)) ) 
      = floor( 64 / 4.7004397181410921603968126542567)
      = floor( 13.6 )
      = 13
```

if you want to know how many bits you need for 50 chars:

```
bits  = ceil( 50 / (log(2)/log(26)) ) 
      = ceil( 50 / 0.21274605355336315360618778415321
      = ceil( 235.02198590705460801984063271284 )
      = 236
```

Now if you want to encode 13 char (`a..z`) from `text` into 64 bit unsigned integer `x`:

```cpp
char text[13] = "bla bla bla b";
unsigned int x,m,i;
for (i=0,x=0,m=1;i<13;i++,m*=26)
 x += ((unsigned int)(text[i]-'a'))*m;
```

And decoding back:

```cpp
for (i=0;i<13;i++)
    {
    text[i] = (x%26)+'a';
    x /= 26;
    }
```

As you can see its the same as converting between numbers in different bases...

In case you want to have faster dec/enc at the cost of text size you can `ceil` the number of bits per single character to `5` meaning `floor(64/5) = 12 chars` and use bits operations instead (each character would be 5 bits in the number)...

```cpp
char text[12] = "bla bla bla ";
unsigned int x,i;
for (i=0,x=0,i<12;i++)
   { 
   x <<= 5;
   x |= text[i]-'a';
   }

for (i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
    text[11-i] = (x&31)+'a';
    x >>= 5;
    }
```

However if you have any additional knowledge about the characters its possible to implement compression but only in cases where entropy allows it... for more info google RLE,Huffman encoding...